# How to show the error code or error on message box

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do i need to show the error/error code on the page when it was catch? because as a user they dont know what kind of error that they facing beside debugging it.

Example :

```
     public List<SelectListItem> PayModeItems()
    {

        try
        {
            List<SelectListItem> paymodeList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            paymodeList.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "CASH",
                Value = "1"
            });
            paymodeList.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "CARD",
                Value = "20",
                
            });
            paymodeList.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "BANK TRANSFER",
                Value = "3",
              });

            return paymodeList;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            string logFilePathTransactionSM = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFilePathTransactionSendMoney"];
            LogtoXmlService.LogServiceErrorWithDetails(ex, "SendMoneyController", "PayModeItems", logFilePathTransactionSM, "SendMoney");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: `catch (Exception e) { /* now you can use e.Message here */ }`

Comment: just put `'e'` after exception? did it will display the the error message or code on page?

Comment: no, but then you can set some displayed field value with e.Message. Or if it's an API,, have a special field "isError" and "errorMessage" set in this case. You have to code for it of course. But maybe try to provide a bit more details if you want us to help you more precisely. How do you usually display something when there is no error ?

Comment: You've tagged this with asp.net? web servers can't just open a "message box", they have to return some http response, which can include text to describe the error. But you haven't provided enough context to help you any further.

Comment: okay i change the example. i taking my real code and i do some error under the `card value`

Comment: Would be great if you can specify which front-end framework that you used. From your code, look like you are using the ASP.NET MVC / razor page.

Comment: yes im using asp.net mvc

Comment: Ok, a possible pattern for this would have a more abstract object `SelectListItemResponse` returned by your action. This object would have 2 properties: a `List<SelectListItem>` (the usual result) , and a `string` (the error message) . You set the string with the error mesage (in the exception block) if there is any. Otherwise, you set the list. Then, when you call the API, you know that if the list is null, then it means you have an error and error message string is not null, and so you display it as you wish on your front end (with a scary red color etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Possible pattern for this:

- have a more abstract object SelectListItemResponse. This object would have 2 properties: a List (the usual result)  and a string (the error message) .
- You set the string with the error mesage (in the exception block) if there is any.
- Otherwise, you set the list.

Then, when you call the API, you get this object in return, and you know that if the list is null, then it means you have an error and error message string is not null, and so you display it as you wish on your front end (with a scary red color etc...)

```cs
public class PayModeItemsResponse
{
    public List<SelectListItem> Result { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}

public List<SelectListItem> PayModeItems()
    {

        try
        {
            List<SelectListItem> paymodeList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            paymodeList.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "CASH",
                Value = "1"
            });
            paymodeList.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "CARD",
                Value = "20",
                
            });
            paymodeList.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "BANK TRANSFER",
                Value = "3",
              });

             return new PayModeItemsResponse { Result = paymodeList };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            string logFilePathTransactionSM = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFilePathTransactionSendMoney"];
            LogtoXmlService.LogServiceErrorWithDetails(ex, "SendMoneyController", "PayModeItems", logFilePathTransactionSM, "SendMoney");

            return new PayModeItemsResponse { ErrorMessage = ex.Message };
        }
    }
```

Comment: so in the VIEW did i need to do javascript as well?

Comment: yes, analyse the response given, if error message is null, then do as you do usually with the result, other wise show error message as you wish.